# Making a Notification API in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, email, notifications

I'm a newbie at c#, but I'm trying to make a notification API that sends email notifications to authenticated users, much like the way Slack sends email notifications when you're away from the app and you've been mentioned or received DMs. I'm using vscode not Visual Studio, so it seems more challenging. The API is going to be used by a web app.

I am firmly convinced that there are tutorials on making this exact API, but I need help finding them. I'd really appreciate it if someone could tell me where to find tutorials on making an email and SMS notification API using C#. Alternatively, I will appreciate a walkthrough on how to create this API.

So far, I have found this tutorial useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/build-web-api-aspnet-core/9-summary. But my question is does anyone know a tutorial that directly targets building an email notification API in C# (not a todo API or other kinds of API)?

Comment: The web API project on its own is not the important part as far as I understand it. The API would need an external trigger (e.g. a client app sending a web request) to do anything as web APIs are (generally) not used for background processes that watch something (e.g. a user going away).

Comment: We also will need more details about the type of software you are building (Is there even a client app? If yes, is it a web or desktop app? etc. etc.). But even then this question might be too broad.

Comment: Ok. Apart from details on the software that will use it, what else will make this question specific enough?

Comment: Not sure ‍♂️ The overlords generally close-vote questions without any code or technical details; if they feel that their is no clear-cut answer; or if they had a hard-boiled egg for breakfast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notification usual consist of parts:

- data colector: Changes in data should be collected in some buffer (database) to be processed later, to don't make influence on existing process. Alternativelly you can execute notification immediatelly, in same thread with editing data.
- template creator: changed data should be transformed to message (email, sms, twitter, html, excel, word, pdf etc). Message it self consist of static and dynamic parts. So you can develop one template for all similar messages. Template consist of text with special placeholders during processing those placeholders should be replaced with dynamic content (with collected data). So somewhere should be developed mechanism to store,edit,update,remove those templates (easiest mode - file system - folder with text files).
- data processor: process/job/task which pickup modified data and record by record using one of template converting to final static message (or document).
- message sending: another job which is trying to send messages by email server, sms server, network hub etc

You could develop own variant - last part could be hard to arrange, because of email box could be blocked in case when lot of messages are going to be send in short time period. sms(twilio), twitter or other services are paible.

You could find and use existing (usual paible) notification service. This service could provide you part of above described points (templates managment, template data processor etc). you just need to send those dynamic data to service api - rest will be executed on service server (aka: mailchimp).

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. It shows the volume of the problem. Please can you recommend any existing API I can use? An API that sends email and SMS notifications preferably built in C# or even Python.

Comment: i am bit far (means long time ago i had development such functionlaity it is better to review other possibilities 2), but as i know you can use: https://www.twilio.com/messaging/sms   
it is webapi, if you familiar with it,  1-2days to develop wrapper above to cover your requirements